# How to stop WebStorm from automatically clearing unused imports

Tags: javascript, webstorm, eslint

I'm using WebStorm 2018.2. I'm working on a preact project that needs the following line `import {h} from preact`. The imported `h` is not used anywhere but it is required to be imported. When I do format with <kbd>Cmd + Alt + L</kbd>, it is clearing off this unused import...

How can I prevent WebStorm from clearing unused imports?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/optimizing-imports.html

Comment: I want to disable optimize imports not enabled them

Comment: it is saying, Open the Reformat File Dialog (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L) and select the Optimize imports checkbox. (so in your case this checkbox should be already enabled, so disable it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reiterating the solution [Helping hand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648253/helping-hand) posted as comment above...

Open the Reformat File Dialog (Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+Alt+L) and unselect the Optimize imports checkbox.